# Pandas: How to get the size of each chunk from big csv file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big csv file having million rows. I would like to read that csv in chunks and save the count of rows of each chunks in dataframe for reference.

```
chunk_size=50000
for chunk in pd.read_csv('file.csv',chunksize=chunk_size):
    print(chunk.shape)
```

I want to save each chunk shape in dataframe. My expected output as below. Please suggest.

```
 column1  column2
 chunk1   50,000
 chunk2   50,000
 chunk3   50,000
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want something like this:

```
sizes = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Chunk", "Size"])
for i, chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv("file.csv", chunksize=50000)):
    sizes.loc[i] = [f"chunk{i+1}", chunk.shape[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
chunk_size=50000
i = 1
lengths = []
names = []
for chunk in pd.read_csv('file.csv',chunksize=chunk_size):
    lengths.append(len(chunk))
    names.append('chunk %s' % i)
    chunk.to_csv('chunk_%s.csv' % i)
    i+=1

df= pd.DataFrame({'size': lengths}, index=names)
```